# module not found error when slate is deployed

Tags: reactjs, slate

[image: error generated on the browser]
[image: Error genrated on the terminal devops]

module not found error shows up even though ihave installed and imported the slate.js

[image: package.json have the dependencies]

this code is properly working on my local machine but on deployement this error is generated

I tried reinstalling the deendencies and clearing the terminal warnings.